# URL images not showing in mobile browser

Tags: html, image, mobile, browser

I am having an issue. I am creating a mobile site for my website which I am running in the WAMP local server. So I created a Subdomain for the mobile site which is `m.localhost` but the problem is this, if I did some things like this

```
$home = "http://localhost";
$image = "/images/image.jpg";

echo "<img src='".$home.$image."' />";
```

And I run the page on my PC browsers it display the image but when I try to run it in my mobile browser emulators I just get a broken image sign, please how do I fix this?

Comment: you see other staffs on the mobile browser..right? Can you see the source(`Ctrl+U`) on mobile browser and find the `<img ..../>` ...what is coded there ?

Comment: I viewed the source code in the mobile chrome emulator and I get this `http://localhost/images/image.jpg` which is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use IP address instead as the URL. So instead of

```
$home = http://localhost";
```

Use this

```
$home = "http://127.0.0.1";  // or whatever IP address that your local server uses
```